# Docker container (for elastic search) starts and exits with error every single time "[Qkskaso] failed to read local state, exiting..."

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to run a docker container using the the follow Elastic Search Image (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.2). Every time I attempt to run this container, it exits during the start up process. The logs showing the error and what follows it below.

- Removing any image related to elastic search
- Docker system prune
- Docker container prune
- Docker volume prune
- Using a different (later, v 6.6.1) docker image will allow it to persist ... this is a temporary fix, but I collaborate with others who use the image with version 6.2.2, without a problem, and I need to be running and deploying the same images.

Unsure of how to resolve this, thanks!

Error starts with

'''

[2019-04-02T11:05:41,952][ERROR][o.e.g.GatewayMetaState   ] [Qkskaso] failed to read local state, exiting...
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:165, legacy:false,

...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected field [mapping_version]

...

'''

I'm not sure how sensitive any of the information in the error code is (if at all, i'm relatively new to docker), so if I need to provide more information, I can.

Expected: docker container runs
Actual: docker container exits

Comment: This seems off topic for StackOverflow, since the question is not related to software development. Regardless, you will want to include in your question the exact command line you are using to start the container.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53702703/elasticsearch-crashes-after-showing-t-failed-to-read-local-state-exiting

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and I sovle it by removing the volume that have the corrupted index.

And then I have create the indecies again.

I think it is a corrupted data inside one of the index, or in your case, it is problem of the diffrent mapping between the two Elasticsearch version you use.